# How to call an inline function in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I wrote an inline function and implemented each basic block call to the inline function in LLVM's pass. However, the compilation error is as follows:

```
inline function call in a function with debug info must have a !dbg location
```

I wonder why? Am I missing a step or a parameter?

[+] the call instruction like this:

```
std::vector<Type*> Vct; 
Vct.push_back(Int32Ty); 
Vct.push_back(Int32Ty); 
ArrayRef<Type*> Args(Vct); 
FunctionType *Ty = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(*Ctx), Args,false);
FunctionCallee callee_ = M.getOrInsertFunction("HH",Ty); 
Value *Args_[] = {IRB.getInt32(a),IRB.getInt32(b)};           
const Twine Name = ""; 

IRB.CreateCall(callee_,Args_,Name);
```

Comment: Your debug metadata is present but incomplete. Complete it and all will be well.

Comment: I have attached my call code, can you help me have a look? Should I go SetCurrentDebugLocation?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I remember that I saw that error message and that I solved it by adding the missing metadata, but I don't remember what they were. Sorry. That's why this is a comment not an answer. I… may remember how I found it, though. I think I found the line in LLVM that emits that message and set a breakpoint, then looked at if()s that led to that point.